# Persisting entities in SpringData without the need to fetch the associations

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I have recently started on a project that uses Spring Boot. I am still learning some concepts but some things related to data access are bothering me a bit. Let me use an example.

I have a couple of entities:

```
@Entity
class Book {
    @Id
    private Long idBook;
    private String title;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "idAuthor")
    private Author author;
}

@Entity
class Author {
    @Id
    private Long idAuthor;
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Book> books;
}
```

For the sake of simplicity lets suppose a Book can have only one Author.

The book repository is a simple interface:

```
public interface BookRepository extends JpaRepository<Book, Long> {}
```

I also have a DTO for books:

```
class BookDTO {
    private Long idBook;
    private String title;
    private idAuthor;
}
```

When a client want to save a book he will send a json like that:

```
{  
   "idBook":328,
   "title":"The Martian Chronicles",
   "idAuthor":56
}
```

Everytime someone needs to save a Book he will convert the DTO to entity and fetch the Author before saving:

```
entityBook.setId(dtoBook.getId());
entityBook.setTitle(dtoBook.getTitle());
entityBook.setAuthor(authorRepository.getById(dtoBook.getIdAuthor()));

bookRepository.save(entityBook);
```

For me it seems a waste of resources as only the idAuthor need to be saved. This is a simple example. The real life situations I am facing are much more complex and can be frustrating sometimes.

I found a solution using the method **EntityManager::getReference**.

[persisting a new object without having to fetch the associations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3429979/persisting-a-new-object-without-having-to-fetch-the-associations)

[Hibernate persist entity without fetching association object. just by id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31929447/hibernate-persist-entity-without-fetching-association-object-just-by-id)

The problem (if I didn't understand it wrong) is: getting a EntityManager reference (injected via @PersistenceContext) outside the Repositories is not a good practice and the conversion from dto to entity is made on a layer before the call to the Repositories.

Is there an alternative way to accomplish this without accessing the EntityManager on upper layers?

Answer (score 1):

You can try setting the author by :

```
Author currentAuthor = new Author();
currentAuther.setIdAuthor(dtoBook.getIdAuthor());
entityBook.setAuthor(currentAuthor);
```

This will not create new Author in case there is an existing one with same Primary key. Please check the Cascade type while setting this